# Merging two sorted lists, one with additional 0s

Tags: merge, sorting

Consider the following problem:

> We are given two arrays `A` and `B` such that `A` and `B` are sorted
>   *except* `A` has `B.length` additional 0s appended to its end. For instance, `A` and `B` could be the following:
>
> ```
> A = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0]
> B = [1, 7, 9]
> ```
>
> Our goal is to create one sorted list by inserting each entry of `B`
>   into `A` *in place*. For instance, running the algorithm on the above
>   example would leave
>
> ```
> A = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 9]
> ```

Is there a clever way to do this in better than O(n^2) time? The only way I could think of is to insert each element of `B` into `A` by scanning linearly and performing the appropriate number of shifts, but this leads to the O(n^2) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `O(n)`.

Work from the end, moving the largest element towards the end of `A`. This way you avoid a lot of trouble to do with where to keep the elements while iterating. This is pretty easy to implement:

```
int indexA = A.Length - B.Length - 1;
int indexB = B.Length - 1;
int insertAt = A.Length;

while (indexA > 0 || indexB > 0)
{
    insertAt--;
    A[insertAt] = max(B[indexB], A[indexA]);
    if (A[indexA] <= B[indexB])
        indexB--;
    else
        indexA--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code (sorta C-ish), assuming array indexing is 0-based:

```
pA = A + len(A) - 1;
pC = pA;                     // last element in A
while (! *pA) --pA;          // find the last non-zero entry in A
pB = B + len(B) - 1;
while (pA >= A) && (pB >= B)
    if *pA > *pB
        *pC = *pA; --pA;
    else
        *pC = *pB; --pB;
    --pC
while (pB >= B)                 // still some bits in B to copy over
    *pC = *pB; --pB; --pC;
```

Not really tested, and just written off the top of my head, but it should give you the idea... May not have the termination and boundary conditions exactly right.